# React useState(0) vs useState( () => 0 )

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I saw React codes generally use arrow function for setState().  However, for useState(), I see that they just put a number, eg useState(0) instead of arrow function, ie useState( () => 0 )

Are there any reasons why I would want to use an arrow function in useState ?   Is it alright to use only arrow functions for ALL React hook regardless, including initialising the hook.  Any gotcha ?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

For your simple case it does not matter. You are just making an extra function call which returns a value without any computation.

But in case your initial state is a result of an expensive computation you can use a function.

Using the below

```
const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
  const initialState = someExpensiveComputation(props);
  return initialState;
});
```

instead of

```
const [state, setState] = useState(someExpensiveComputation(props));
```

matters greatly.

**The initialState argument is the state used during the initial render. In subsequent renders, it is disregarded.**

So even when your value is disregarded you would be making that expensive computation. You can provide a function in your useState which will only run on the very first render, like in the second case above. [Link](The initialState argument is the state used during the initial render. In subsequent renders, it is disregarded.)

Comment: I see.  So using a function will prevent recalculation in subsequent renders.  I see that you've said that it does not matter whether I use a value or a function for useState for a simple case.  However, I would like to know if it's ok to use an arrow function for all situations.  I thought of maintaining consistent coding and do away with selecting an option to use in different situations.

Comment: I guess it does not matter. It is a minor computation after all. If you are looking for consistency in code. I would personally not do it as every call matters :P

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the arrow functions in state setter permit use the previous state.
For example:

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState('hello ')
... # Receive data from a form or API, etc.
let name = 'Richard'
setMessage(old_state => old_state + name) # 'hello Richard'
```

This way, you can create counter or reuse some data of the previous state.

Use `setState(new_vale)` is totally correct for reset the value.

Comment: question is about using callback in the `useState` rather for setter which `useState` returns